# Cannot begin figure after using \tikzset to redefine basis vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I am drawing several TikZ pictures in which I would like the basis vectors to be rotated from the usual definition, so I have used the command

```
\tikzset{x={(0cm,-1cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}}
```

in my preamble. However, after doing so, I cannot create figures (I receive the undefined control sequence error message for whatever follows `\begin{figure}`). Any full redefinition of the basis vectors causes the same problem. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
text
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I do not get the error if I only rescale using, for example, `\tikzset{x=-1}`.

My current workaround is to put the `\tikzset` command inside each TikZ picture.

What is causing this error? Is there a way to redefine basis vectors globally that avoids it?

Comment: Welcome! I can't reproduce your error. When was the last time you updated your TeX installation? (You could try `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)}}}`, but I can't tell if that helps since I cannot reproduce your error.)

Comment: I'm using Overleaf. Your suggestion works for me---thank you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done. (Needless to say that I will be happy to remove it if it is too obvious.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, upvoted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to apply some style of this sort to every picture is to use the key `every picture`. In your case you could say

```
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={x={(0cm,-1cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}}}
```

which, unless you have done some other transformations, should have the same effect at

```
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={rotate=-90}}
```

The second variant has the slight advantage of being applicable on top of other transformations.